# How do I download and install EPICSQt on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, qt

I am installing EPICS (Experimental Physics and Industrial Control System) in my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1.

EPICS need to be built in many parts, I have built EPICS Base, SynApps, Extension. Now I need to build a GUI for my EPICS, EPICSQt is a GUI for EPICS.

I need the download link for EPICSQt and installation procedure for it.

Answer (score 1):

EPICSQt is available from SourceForge [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/epicsqt/files/documentation/). The installation instructions are provided in that download, in the QE_GettingStarted.pdf file in the documents folder.